# How to create reusable build configuration in maven?

Tags: java, maven, build

I have java project building using maven with several sub-modules that are build the very same way: there is executable jar, dependency jars in lib directory, some resources etc.

Configuration among modules differs only in main-class. So, I want to create some sort of preconfigured build (or macros, or whatever) to not copy same configuration of build plugins to different pom.xml modules but to reuse same configuration with main-class as a parameter.

How can I achieve this?

(Build configuration: http://pastebin.com/9Fm5rFK7)

Comment: [Maven - Inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) Something like this?

Comment: I use inheritance (for dependencies and basic build configurations like source level), but I could not use it  for build configuration: maven tries to use it for 'parent' project (for which this rules can't be applied) and fails to build.

Comment: Can you provide some excerpts from your pom.xml files and perhaps a sketch of your project structure? Another option is to [create a custom Maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html)

Comment: I considered that possibility but in this case I will loose all simplicity and maintainability. I'm really disappointed that it's hard to do such basic things with maven. I've updated post with link to my build configuration.

Comment: Inheritance + `pluginManagement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parameterized them with maven [properties](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties), override them after it is [inherited](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance). In your case, you can introduce mainClass property and use it in your plugin configuration from the parent module, for example `<mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>`. This properties then can be overridden in the child modules.

EDIT:
For the parent pom, I was referring to the pluginManagement section (Sorry for the unclearness). I have created an example with your build configuration here:
https://gist.github.com/ceilfors/5827916

I think that's the minimum that you can get in the child module. `maven-jar-plugin` is optional because of the jar packaging type. Refer to the [lifecycle bindings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) and you can see that the plugin will be called during `package` phase.

Also, when your project gets more complex, you can explore on how to [merge](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/) the plugin configuration too. I have created another example here: https://gist.github.com/ceilfors/5828039. Note that properties for mainClass was not used.

Hope this helps.